# Cleaning Dataframe in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe (haveleft) full of people who have left a service and their reason for leaving. The 'text' column is their reason, but some of them aren't strings. Not many, so I just want to remove those rows, either in place or to a new dataframe. Below code just gives me a dataframe populated with only NaN. Why doesn't it work?

```
cleanedleft = pd.DataFrame()
cleanedleft = haveleft[haveleft[haveleft['text'] == str]]
print(holder[0:10])
```

or if I remove one of the 'haveleft[ ]' I get an empty dataframe

```
cleanedleft = pd.DataFrame()
cleanedleft = haveleft[haveleft['text'] == str]
print(holder[0:10])
```

I've tried to add a type() but can't seem to figure out the way to do this.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Your code has too many levels of indexing and is based on an incorrect assumption that a text string is equal to the datatype `str`. All values in a DataFrame column belong to the same datatype. If any of them is a string, then all others must be strings, too - unless all values were converted to the class `object`. What is the actual datatype of the column? Please post a sample of your data.

Comment: What is your desired output? a dataframe with one column? many columns?

Comment: Good catch on excessive 'haveleft[ ]' without it I get an empty dataframe. I've tried to include a type() but can't seem to just stick it in there/don't know how to properly include it. Here's the header and first row: id order_id user_id text 1 3885 12878 Rash on face the goal is to have the dataframe but without the rows where the text column is not a string. In place or new dataframe, happy with either

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because DataFrame columns cannot contain mixed types; your `text` column will be string or object, even if some values are numerical. You'll want to figure out how to characterize unwanted data and drop them accordingly.

For instance, to drop rows where 'text' consists only of digits as in the single-line example you give:

```
cleaned = df[~df['text'].str.match('^\d+$')]
```